# What is the maximum number of columns in a PostgreSQL select query

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.2

Do you know what the maximum number of columns that can be queried in Postgresql? I need to know this  before I start my project.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12155777/max-number-of-tables-in-postgresql-select-query

Comment: I have a rare need to put a high amount of columns in the table. No way around it without causing serious pain.

Comment: While highly suspicious of database design problems, this is still a valid question. Related advice cannot replace the answer.

Comment: Do you need each one to be a unique column?  Could serialized data or arrays help here?

Comment: Adding to @Scott's comment: .. or [hstore](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/hstore.html), maybe?

Comment: Actually, yes - I will need individual columns. I will be importing CSV thousands of files in tables to analyse. Some CSV files have many many columns. Also, some integer and date columns will need indexes.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

According to [PostgreSQL Limits](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/limits.html) it's "250 - 1600 depending on column types". See note under the table. The column types affect it because in PostgreSQL rows may be at most 8kb (one page) wide, they cannot span pages. Big values in columns are OK because TOAST handles that, but there's a limit to how many columns you can fit in that depends on how wide the un-TOASTed data types used are.

(Strictly this refers to columns that can be stored in on-disk rows; queries might be able to use wider column sets than this. I don't recommend relying on it.)

If you're even thinking about approaching the column limits you're probably going to have issues.

Mapping spreadsheets to relational databases seems like the simplest thing in the world - map columns to columns, rows to rows, and go. Right? In reality, spreadsheets are huge freeform monsters that enforce no structure and can be really unweildy. Relational databases are designed to handle *lots* more rows, but at a cost; in the case of PostgreSQL part of that cost is a limitation to how wide it likes those rows to be. When facing spreadsheets created by Joe User this can be a real problem.

One "solution" is to decompose them into [EAV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model), but that's unspeakably slow and ugly to work with. Better solutions are using arrays where possible, composite types, `hstore`, json, xml, etc.

In the end, though, sometimes the best answer is to analyse the spreadsheet using a spreadsheet.

Comment: Wow..I am very familiar with sql server and my first time using postgresql. I had no idea a database had hstore and json. You gave me a good idea to solve another problem by using these datatypes. I see postgresql is a powerful tool.

Comment: By the way, major new features for JSON support are coming with Postgres 9.4. Available now as a beta. XML support is already excellent. And Postgres has had key-value pair support (hstore) long before the "No-SQL" label was coined. Powerful indeed.

Answer (score 11):

For others who might find this information useful the answer is 1663 depending on the types of columns occording to this post
http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-admin/2008-05/msg00208.php

Answer (score 0):

With the use of the JSON/JSONB type, there almost is no need to have very many columns in a table.

And in rare cases, if you were to hit the maximum column limit of your database system, maybe you could use an RDBMS implementation of a spreadsheet, with a table like the following:

```
create table wide_table(
id serial not null primary key
,rownum integer not null
,colnum integer not null
,colname varchar(30) not null
,coltype varchar(30) not null
,nullable boolean   not null
,collen  integer
,colprec integer
,colscale integer
,colvalue raw(2000)
,unique (rownum,colnum)
);
```

This would allow for practically unlimited number of columns, but using it would be less trivial.