# How to check many columns for boundaries set in another table?

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions, plpgsql

I'm using **PostgreSQL `v10.12`**

**Table 1: Threshold** with total rows `~800` (Each sensor's minimum and maximum threshold level is store in this table)

Description:

```
SensorName Varchar(10), 
MinLimit numeric, 
MaxLimit numeric
```

Data:

```
SensorName | MinLimit | MaxLimit
Sensor1    | 80       | 115
Sensor2    | 60       | 70
Sensor3    | 100      | 120
...
Sensor800  | 60       | 70
```

**Table 2: IoTData** with total columns `~800+` (Each sensor in Threshold table is the column in IoTData table)

Description:

```
IoTDateTime timestamp without time zone, 
sensor1 numeric(3)
sensor2 numeric(8,5)
sensor3 numeric(5,2)
....
Sensor800 numeric(5,2)
```

For every 5 minutes record will be generated in this table.
This table is partitioned with date range (4 months data will be in a partition). Likewise there are 6 partitions in for this table so far.

*e.g:

```
        IoTDateTime         |   Sensor1
    2020-01-01 11:05:00     |      85
    2020-01-01 11:10:00     |      80
    2020-01-01 11:15:00     |      77
    ...
    2020-01-31 23:50:00     |      70
    2020-01-31 23:55:00     |      70
```

From Table 1 `Threshold` this `Sensor1`'s `MinLimit` is `80` and `MaxLimit` is `115`. Anything below `MinLimit` (`80`) or greater than `MaxLimit` (`115`) is considered as alert or sensor is malfunctioning.

**I need to find the alert count of all 800+ sensors for each day of a month.**

I wrote below function to perform this logic.

Need your help to rewrite this function in better way to reduce the line of code and optimistic logic.
**Thanks in advance :)**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.udf_SensorFailedForeachDay
(   pimono integer,
    pstartdate timestamp without time zone,
    penddate timestamp without time zone)

    RETURNS TABLE(date_of_month double precision, Sensor1 double precision, Sensor2 double precision, 
    ...
    , Sensor800 double precision) 
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    COST 100
    VOLATILE 
    ROWS 1000
AS $BODY$

declare Sensor1min  numeric(3);declare Sensor1max  numeric(3);

declare Sensor2min  numeric(8,5);declare Sensor2max  numeric(8,5);
....
declare Sensor800min  numeric(5,2);declare Sensor800max  numeric(5,2);
BEGIN

select minlimit,maxlimit Into Sensor1min,Sensor1max from threshold where channelname='Sensor1';
select minlimit,maxlimit Into Sensor2min,Sensor2max from threshold where channelname='Sensor2';
...

select minlimit,maxlimit Into Sensor800min,Sensor800max from threshold where channelname='Sensor800';
Return query 
select extract(day from a.IoTDateTime) as date_of_month,
(cast(sum(case when a.Sensor1 between Sensor1min and Sensor1max then 1 end) as float)/cast(count(a.IoTDateTime) as float) )*100 as Sensor1,
(cast(sum(case when a.Sensor2 between Sensor2min and Sensor2max then 1 end) as float)/cast(count(a.IoTDateTime) as float))*100 as Sensor2,
...
(cast(sum(case when a.Sensor800 between Sensor800min and Sensor800max then 1 end) as float)/cast(count(a.IoTDateTime) as float))*100 as Sensor800
from IoTData a where a.IoTDateTime between Pstartdate and Penddate
group by extract(day from a.IoTDateTime) order by extract(day from a.IoTDateTime);

END;
$BODY$;
```

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but: you only need one `declare` section for all variables, not one for each variable.

Comment: You need to change your label. PLSQL is Oracle's proprietary language extension for sql. For Postgres it is plpgsql (extension language) or pslq (command line interface).

Comment: Thanks. changed the label

Comment: When i tried one declare for all variable got ERROR:  syntax error at or near ","
e.g: declare Sensor1min  numeric(3),Sensor1max  numeric(3);

Comment: Keyword `DECLARE` should be used only once per block - please, start by reading documentation - https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-declarations.html

Comment: `I need to find the alert count ...` So you just need a *count* of offending sensors per day? Please be precise what you actually need. Maybe show an exact (minimum) example of the desired result.

Comment: Thanks. Earlier I 've tried to use comma after datatype but that since i got error i've used multiple delare. (In MS SQL Server I've used comma) declare Sensor1min  numeric(3), Sensor1max  numeric(3); Later after reading above URL I've used semicolon declare Sensor1min  numeric(3);Sensor1max  numeric(3); and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a *fixed* number of sensors and hardly ever update rows, storing data in `IoTData` with a single row per timestamp, like you did, can make sense to get minimum storage size and good performance.

**However**, you are getting close to the absolute maximum number of columns allowed, which is an indicator that you may be moving in the wrong direction. See:

- [Database Columns In Select or create statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13639626/database-columns-in-select-or-create-statements/13639920#13639920)

If you later need to add / remove sensors, you have to adapt the table structure and everything that depends on it, including the function I am going to supply. A painful process. So, typically, it would be more reasonable to use a more generic model with one row per measurement (800 rows instead of just 1). That bloats storage, but is much more versatile.

That said, it can work like this:

> ```
> CREATE TEMP TABLE threshold (
>    sensorname varchar(10), 
>    minlimit numeric, 
>    maxlimit numeric
> );
>
> INSERT INTO threshold VALUES
>   ('Sensor1', 80 , 115)
> , ('Sensor2', 60 , 70)
> , ('Sensor3', 100, 120)
> -- more
> ;
>
> CREATE TABLE iotdata (
>    iotdatetime timestamp PRIMARY KEY
>  , sensor1 numeric(3)
>  , sensor2 numeric(8,5)
>  , sensor3 numeric(5,2)
> );
>
> INSERT INTO iotdata VALUES
>   ('2020-01-01 11:05:00', 85, 65, 110)
> , ('2020-01-01 11:10:00', 86, 11, 109)  -- low
> , ('2020-01-01 11:15:00', 77, 15, 666)  -- low + hi
> ;
> ```

> ```
> TABLE threshold;
> ```
>
> ```
> sensorname | minlimit | maxlimit
> :--------- | -------: | -------:
> Sensor1    |       80 |      115
> Sensor2    |       60 |       70
> Sensor3    |      100 |      120
> ```

> ```
> -- pivot table threshold to match pivoted data
> CREATE TABLE dim_threshold AS
> SELECT *
> FROM  crosstab(
>  $$(
>    SELECT 'min' AS dimension, sensorname, minlimit
>    FROM   threshold
>    ORDER  BY sensorname
>    )
>    UNION ALL
>    (
>    SELECT 'max' AS dimension, sensorname, maxlimit
>    FROM   threshold
>    ORDER  BY sensorname
>    )$$
>    , $$(SELECT unnest('{Sensor1,Sensor2,Sensor3}'::text[]))$$
>    ) AS (dimension text, sensor1 numeric, sensor2 numeric, sensor3 numeric);
>
> TABLE dim_threshold;
> ```
>
> ```
> dimension | sensor1 | sensor2 | sensor3
> :-------- | ------: | ------: | ------:
> min       |      80 |      60 |     100
> max       |     115 |      70 |     120
> ```

> ```
> TABLE iotdata;
> ```
>
> ```
> iotdatetime         | sensor1 |  sensor2 | sensor3
> :------------------ | ------: | -------: | ------:
> 2020-01-01 11:05:00 |      85 | 65.00000 |  110.00
> 2020-01-01 11:10:00 |      86 | 11.00000 |  109.00
> 2020-01-01 11:15:00 |      77 | 15.00000 |  666.00
> ```

> ```
> -- aux function to calculate percentage
> CREATE FUNCTION f_calc_pct(bigint, bigint)
>   RETURNS float LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE PARALLEL SAFE AS
> 'SELECT ($1 * 100)::float / $2';
> ```

> ```
> -- main function
> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION udf_sensor_fail_per_day(pstartdate timestamp
>                                                  , penddate   timestamp)
>   RETURNS TABLE(the_day date, dimenstion text, sensor1 float, sensor2 float, sensor3 float) -- more?
>   LANGUAGE sql ROWS 100 AS
> $func$
> WITH cte AS (
>    SELECT iotdatetime::date AS the_day
>         , count(*) AS ct
>         , count(*) FILTER (WHERE i.sensor1 < min.sensor1) AS s1_min
>         , count(*) FILTER (WHERE i.sensor2 < min.sensor2) AS s2_min
>         , count(*) FILTER (WHERE i.sensor3 < min.sensor3) AS s3_min
>       -- more ...
>         , count(*) FILTER (WHERE i.sensor1 > max.sensor1) AS s1_max
>         , count(*) FILTER (WHERE i.sensor2 > max.sensor2) AS s2_max
>         , count(*) FILTER (WHERE i.sensor3 > max.sensor3) AS s3_max
>       -- more ...
>    FROM   iotdata i
>    CROSS  JOIN (SELECT * FROM dim_threshold WHERE dimension = 'min') min
>    CROSS  JOIN (SELECT * FROM dim_threshold WHERE dimension = 'max') max
>    WHERE  iotdatetime >= pstartdate
>    AND    iotdatetime <  penddate
>    GROUP  BY 1
>    )
> SELECT the_day, 'min' AS dimension
>      , f_calc_pct(s1_min, ct) -- AS s1
>      , f_calc_pct(s2_min, ct) -- AS s2
>      , f_calc_pct(s3_min, ct) -- AS s3
>     -- more ...
> FROM   cte
> UNION ALL
> SELECT the_day, 'max' AS dimension
>      , f_calc_pct(s1_max, ct) -- AS s1
>      , f_calc_pct(s2_max, ct) -- AS s2
>      , f_calc_pct(s3_max, ct) -- AS s3
>     -- more ...
> FROM   cte;
> $func$;
> ```

> ```
> -- call
> SELECT * FROM udf_sensor_fail_per_day('2020-01-01 00:00', '2020-01-11 00:00');
> ```
>
> ```
> the_day    | dimenstion | sensor1          | sensor2          | sensor3         
> :--------- | :--------- | :--------------- | :--------------- | :---------------
> 2020-01-01 | min        | 33.3333333333333 | 66.6666666666667 | 0               
> 2020-01-01 | max        | 0                | 0                | 33.3333333333333
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=aec853b7d8992a67d1fbe41dcd2ae388)*