# size/length limitation of array type in PostgreSQL

Tags: arrays, postgresql

I'm working on a web project with PostgreSQL as a databases. I'm trying to build a structure of the web's databases that include a vector space model table.
I created a table with attribute `terms` and `docId[]` where `docId` is the document ID of the term. Type of the `docId` is `integer[]`. So I can input a term with the document list that include the term in one single array. But the docId's array of term may contain a lot of entries.

So my question is: what is the max size of a 1-dimension array in Postgres?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is [no size limit](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/arrays.html) on Postgres arrays.  There must be limits on row or column size, but that would run in the millions of entries.

A more SQL way to relate term to document is a 1 to many relation.  This is implemented like:

```
table term: columns term_id, term, document_id
table document: columns document_id, summary, ...
```

The `document_id` column in the `term` table is called a foreign key.

Comment: "there must be limits on row or column size, but that would run in the millions of entries" – if you would forgive an egregious "well actually": there's a hard limit of 1,600 columns per table, and that limit includes columns that have been deleted: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12612255/71522

Comment: Actually, PostgreSQL has a [max field length of 1GB](https://www.postgresql.org/about/). So, if any term has more than 1GB of "document_ids" (-> one to many), it would exceed PostgreSQL capacities.

Answer (score 17):

I didn't find any limitation in number of elements in array, but there is in field size. Maximum size of field in PostgreSQL is 1GB, so it is approximately 268435456 elements in array. Be aware that indexing such array or searching through it would probably be useless.

Comment: can you please explain why is that? why would index be useless for such array? thanks...

Comment: @cinfis Because that index will be huge. In fact it would probably be bigger than rest of database.

Comment: I'm here trying to find out practical limits on the size of arrays used as function parameters and = ANY clauses: if my function accepts an array of ids to use for selecting rows from a table, is it going to be terribly slow if the array is in the thousands? tens of thousands? ... I should probably try to construct a temp table or something rather than just passing an array of ids...