# Strange results when querying nested objects

Tags: elasticsearch

**Elasticsearch version**: 2.3.3

**Plugins installed**: no plugin

**JVM version**: 1.8.0_91

**OS version**: Linux version 3.19.0-56-generic (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1)

I get strange results when I query [nested objects](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html) on multiple paths. I want to search for all `female` with `dementia`. And there are matched patients among the results. But I also get other diagnoses I'm not looking for, the diagnoses related to these patients.

For example, I also get the following diagnoses despite the fact that I looked only for `dementia`.

- Mental disorder, not otherwise specified
- Essential (primary) hypertension

Why is that? 
I want to get **only** `female` with `dementia` and don't want other diagnoses.

`Client_Demographic_Details` contains one document per patient. `Diagnosis` contains multiple documents per patient. The ultimate goal is to index my whole data from PostgreSQL DB (72 tables, [over 1600 columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12606842/what-is-the-maximum-number-of-columns-in-a-postgresql-select-query) in total) into Elasticsearch.

**Query:**

```
{'query': {
       'bool': {
           'must': [
               {'nested': {
                   'path': 'Diagnosis',
                   'query': {
                       'bool': {
                           'must': [{'match_phrase': {'Diagnosis.Diagnosis': {'query': "dementia"}}}]
                       }  
                   }
               }},
               {'nested': {
                   'path': 'Client_Demographic_Details',
                   'query': {
                       'bool': {
                           'must': [{'match_phrase': {'Client_Demographic_Details.Gender_Description': {'query': "female"}}}]
                       }  
                   }
               }}
           ]
       }
    }}
```

**Results:**

```
{
  "hits": {
    "hits": [
      {
        "_score": 3.4594634, 
        "_type": "Patient", 
        "_id": "72", 
        "_source": {
          "Client_Demographic_Details": [
            {
              "Gender_Description": "Female", 
              "Patient_ID": 72, 
            }
          ], 
          "Diagnosis": [
            {
              "Diagnosis": "F00.0 -  Dementia in Alzheimer's disease with early onset", 
              "Patient_ID": 72, 
            }, 
            {
              "Patient_ID": 72, 
              "Diagnosis": "F99.X -  Mental disorder, not otherwise specified", 
            }, 
            {
              "Patient_ID": 72, 
              "Diagnosis": "I10.X -  Essential (primary) hypertension", 
            }
          ]
        }, 
        "_index": "denorm1"
      }
    ], 
    "total": 6, 
    "max_score": 3.4594634
  }, 
  "_shards": {
    "successful": 5, 
    "failed": 0, 
    "total": 5
  }, 
  "took": 8, 
  "timed_out": false
}
```

**Mapping:**

```
{
  "denorm1" : {
    "aliases" : { },
    "mappings" : {
      "Patient" : {
        "properties" : {
          "Client_Demographic_Details" : {
            "type" : "nested",
            "properties" : {
              "Patient_ID" : {
                "type" : "long"
              },
              "Gender_Description" : {
                "type" : "string"
              }
            }
          },
          "Diagnosis" : {
            "type" : "nested",
            "properties" : {
              "Patient_ID" : {
                "type" : "long"
              },
              "Diagnosis" : {
                "type" : "string"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "settings" : {
      "index" : {
        "creation_date" : "1473974457603",
        "number_of_shards" : "5",
        "number_of_replicas" : "1",
        "uuid" : "Jo9cI4kRQjeWcZ7WMB6ZAw",
        "version" : {
          "created" : "2030399"
        }
      }
    },
    "warmers" : { }
  }
}
```

Comment: have you tried to run the 2 must clauses not in 2 nested blocks, but in 1 nested block instead? - here is an example for that: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-query.html

Comment: @Hansa as far as I understand you must define a `path` to a nested object which you want to query. And there is only one `path` per nested query. That's why you need multiple nested queries - to define multiple `paths`.

Comment: okay, what i didn't noticed was the m:n mapping between Diagnosis and Client_Demographic_Details (Patient) within the same document.

I would rethink this structure, it looks like a very relational-database-approach to me.

In general its better to have ONE document for EACH patient with all his/her Diagnosis. The docu about handling relationsships in Elasticsearch explains that quite well: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/denormalization.html

If you change that structure, queries also get much easier.

Comment: @Hansa but with your solution I face cross-object matching problem, don't I? It is described here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/nested-objects.html

Comment: why do you have `Client_Demographic_Details` as nested, are there multiple value ?

Comment: @blackmamba `Client_Demographic_Details` doesn't contain multiple values. One doc per patient. `Diagnosis` - yes, it contains, multiple diagnoses per patient.

Comment: then you should have taken `Client_Demographic_Details` as an object only.

Comment: @trex no cross-object matching isn't the case then. btw: blackmamba is right :)

Comment: @Hansa @blackmamba So, you are saying that I need to have `Client_Demographic_Details` not nested and `Diagnosis` as nested object in the same document, aren't you?

Comment: yes, that would be better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
{
  "_source": {
    "exclude": [
      "Client_Demographic_Details",
      "Diagnosis"
    ]
  },
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "Diagnosis",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "match_phrase": {
                      "Diagnosis.Diagnosis": {
                        "query": "dementia"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            },
            "inner_hits": {}
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "Client_Demographic_Details",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "match_phrase": {
                      "Client_Demographic_Details.Gender_Description": {
                        "query": "female"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            },
            "inner_hits": {}
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Matched doc on nested will be inside `inner hits` and rest in source. 
i know it's not a concrete approach

Comment: Brilliant, it works! Could you please explain how it works? Or give a link to documentation.

Comment: Why is it not a concrete approach?

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-inner-hits.html

Answer (score 0):

As @blackmamba suggested, I constructed mapping with `Client_Demographic_Details` as root object and `Diagnosis` as a nested object.

**Mapping:**

```
{
  "denorm2" : {
    "aliases" : { },
    "mappings" : {
      "Patient" : {
        "properties" : {
          "BRC_ID" : {
            "type" : "long"
          },
          "Diagnosis" : {
            "type" : "nested",
            "properties" : {
              "BRC_ID" : {
                "type" : "long"
              },
              "Diagnosis" : {
                "type" : "string"
              }
            }
          },
          "Gender_Description" : {
            "type" : "string"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "settings" : {
      "index" : {
        "creation_date" : "1474031740689",
        "number_of_shards" : "5",
        "number_of_replicas" : "1",
        "uuid" : "fMeKa6sfThmxkg_281WdHA",
        "version" : {
          "created" : "2030399"
        }
      }
    },
    "warmers" : { }
  }
}
```

**Query:**

I added source filtering and highlight.

```
{
'_source': {
    'exclude': ['Diagnosis'],
    'include': ['BRC_ID', 'Gender_Description']
},
'highlight': {
    'fields': {
        'Gender_Description': {}
    }                
},
'query': {
    'bool': {
        'must': [
            {'nested': {
                'path': 'Diagnosis',
                'query': {
                    'bool': {
                        'must': [{'match_phrase': {'Diagnosis.Diagnosis': {'query': "dementia"}}}]
                    }  
                },
                'inner_hits': {
                    'highlight': {
                        'fields': {
                            'Diagnosis.Diagnosis': {}    
                        }    
                    },    
                    '_source': ['BRC_ID', 'Diagnosis']
                }
            }},
            {'match_phrase': {'Gender_Description': {'query': "female"}}}
        ]
    }
}}
```