# Flattening or pivoting a table with subjects/tasks from a study with PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have a large table of data in a PostgreSQL database from a research study where a number of test subjects performed a number of tasks, and several sensors gathered data while they performed these tasks. I need to create a table with only one row for each subject, and columns corresponding to the sensor measurements for each task. A simplified example of what I am trying to achieve:
[image: Sample data and sample output]

A couple of key issues:

- I have already aggregated the data I need so there is only one row for each subject/task combination.
- Not all subjects are guaranteed to have completed every task. If a subject has not completed a task, there is no corresponding subject/task row.
- The output needs to have a column corresponding to every possible combination of sensor and task.
- The actual table I am working with has *37 columns* of sensor data, *24 tasks*, and each task was performed *twice* in a pre and post session. Thus the number of columns I need is `37x24x2=1776` columns of data!

---

I could create a new view for every task and then do an outer join on the subject column, but that would still require manually creating a separate view for all 24 tasks and specifying names for all 1776 columns.

**How do I build a query which automatically creates the necessary columns?**

Comment: Create the columns, but in what kind of object? A table cannot have 1776 columns unless recompiling with larger pages. See [What is the maximum number of columns in a PostgreSQL select query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12606842)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a few particular problems here:

1. Queries need to know columns at the outset for planning purposes.
2. You want to do a fairly massive pivot.

I suspect that tablefunc's crosstab function will help a lot (or could be hacked to do what you want if necessary since it was written to be an example of a C-language table valued function).  However you would still have to generate the crosstab criteria outside the query and run it.

This leads to two options for doing this:

1. Create the query outside the db and feed it in with the massive cross tab or
2. Create the cross tab inside the database in a pl/pgsql stored procedure and return a refcursor.

I suspect in most cases, the first is better.

Comment: How would I generate the cross tab? Would I want to use string manipulation in something like python? Are there better ways to go about it?

Answer (score 1):

You can increase postgresql column count.  The info at the following link :

https://manual.limesurvey.org/Instructions_for_increasing_the_maximum_number_of_columns_in_PostgreSQL_on_Linux

Additional,  json type columns may be a good alternative for large column set.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit about using son column types?

Answer (score 0):

Postgresql is very well documented,  please check the postgresql help on Web site or download pdf document.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-json.html

Comment: What I mean was, how would JSON column types help me out with this particular problem?