# PostgreSQL merge many tables to create new table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 34 tables, each one has 17,000 rows and 500 columns. I would like to merge them so I have in the end 17,000 rows and 17,000 columns. The rows are labeled with numbers (0:17000). The columns are (0:500) , (501:1000) , etc.

After merging the tables the column labels should be (0:17000).

Comment: [What is the maximum number of columns in a PostgreSQL select query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12612255/1995738)

Comment: 500 columns per table sounds like a very bad design. 17k column... Are you sure that you know what you are doing?

Comment: This is a really terrible idea for a **relational** database, suggest you research "normalization" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form

Comment: Better use NoSQL Databases to this much of columns

Comment: You may consider reformatting your ending table as JSON or something else.
Question: are these 500 columns (or 17000 columns) all the same data type?

Comment: Thanks guys for the feedback! I am definitely redesigning what I am working on.