# PostgreSQL - from long to wide format

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let's assume I've got some table in long format, like this:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE tmp (
  id int,  
  value varchar,
  id2 int,
  key int);

INSERT INTO tmp VALUES 
  (1, 87.1, 1444, 102),
  (2, 144.9, 13921, 3), 
  (3, 'A032333', 13921, 7),
  (4, 88.9, 13921, 102),
  (5, 'JDS-SJDDD', 13921, 101),
  (6, 90000, 13921, 140),
  (7, 101.1, 33113, 133),
  (8, 'KKL-KKIDD', 33113, 101),
  (9, 0, 33113, 239),
  (10, 933.1, 33113, 250);
```

I'd need to convert this data to wide format, like this:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE tmp2 (
  id2 integer,
  k3 numeric,
  k7 varchar,
  k101 varchar,
  k102 numeric,
  k133 numeric,
  k140 int,
  k239 int,
  k250 numeric);

INSERT INTO tmp2 VALUES 
  (1444, NULL, NULL, NULL, 87.1, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
  (13921, 144.9, 'A032333', 'JDS-SJDDD', 88.9, NULL, 90000, NULL, NULL), 
  (33113, NULL, NULL, 'KKL-KKIDD', NULL, 101.1, NULL, 0, 933.1);
```

I have tried with multiple `CASE WHEN`:

```
SELECT id2, 
    CASE WHEN key = 3 THEN value END AS a3,
    CASE WHEN key = 7 THEN value END AS a7,
    CASE WHEN key = 101 THEN value END AS a101,
    CASE WHEN key = 102 THEN value END AS a102,
    CASE WHEN key = 133 THEN value END AS a133,
    CASE WHEN key = 140 THEN value END AS a140,
    CASE WHEN key = 239 THEN value END AS a239,
    CASE WHEN key = 250 THEN value END AS a250
FROM tmp;
```

However, the output preserves multiple rows for id2 while it would be sufficient to preserve only one per value. How it can be adjusted? I was thinking about something like `GROUP BY` + `COALESCE`, but `COALESCE` looks for values across row and I need to return first not-null value with respect to columns. What's more, this approach seems to be highly cumbersome as my original data would contain around 2000 resulting columns, so specifying each column with `CASE WHEN` will produce large code. Is there any shortcut? If not, how it can be accomplished?

Comment: a late side note: PostgreSQL probably won't support 2000 columns: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12606842/what-is-the-maximum-number-of-columns-in-a-postgresql-select-query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `group by id2` and aggregate:

```
SELECT id2, 
    max(CASE WHEN key = 3 THEN value END) AS a3,
    max(CASE WHEN key = 7 THEN value END) AS a7,
    max(CASE WHEN key = 101 THEN value END) AS a101,
    max(CASE WHEN key = 102 THEN value END) AS a102,
    max(CASE WHEN key = 133 THEN value END) AS a133,
    max(CASE WHEN key = 140 THEN value END) AS a140,
    max(CASE WHEN key = 239 THEN value END) AS a239,
    max(CASE WHEN key = 250 THEN value END) AS a250
FROM tmp
group by id2
order by id2
```

This will work for your sample data.
See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_8.4&fiddle=fe40ba284d84b03deb0630451d9484ba).
Results:

```
>   id2 | a3    | a7      | a101      | a102 | a133  | a140  | a239 | a250 
> ----: | :---- | :------ | :-------- | :--- | :---- | :---- | :--- | :----
>  1444 | null  | null    | null      | 87.1 | null  | null  | null | null 
> 13921 | 144.9 | A032333 | JDS-SJDDD | 88.9 | null  | 90000 | null | null 
> 33113 | null  | null    | KKL-KKIDD | null | 101.1 | null  | 0    | 933.1
```

Comment: How does aggregate function MAX works here?

Answer (score 4):

Postgres supports the `filter` keyword for conditional aggregation, so I recommend:

```
SELECT id2, 
       MAX(value) FILTER (WHERE key = 3) AS a3,
       MAX(value) FILTER (WHERE key = 7) AS a7,
       MAX(value) FILTER (WHERE key = 101) AS a101,
       MAX(value) FILTER (WHERE key = 102) AS a102,
       MAX(value) FILTER (WHERE key = 133) AS a133,
       MAX(value) FILTER (WHERE key = 140) AS a140,
       MAX(value) FILTER (WHERE key = 239) AS a239,
       MAX(value) FILTER (WHERE key = 250) AS a250
FROM tmp
GROUP BY id2;
```

But the key idea is the `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Love the `FILTER` approach vs the `CASE` stmt! Thank you. `crosstab` from `tablefunc` is really nice, but doesn't work in all situations due to the need to "quote" the query.

Comment: @apinstein . . . Filter is also a bit faster.  If you have a question about `filter` then you can ask a question.